# Single Lookup Table Talend in Multiple tmaps

Tags: lookup, talend, lookup-tables, tmap

I am using Talend to do some ETL on some tables from my Database.

I need to do the same tMap operation between the same tables for 3 times, but on different fields.

Since the lookup table is big (100 Milion records), I am wondering if there is some way to load it just once and use the same lookup table for the 3 different tMap components.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can read the table and write it to a `tHashOutput` component and use `tHashInput` to read the data from `tHashOutput`.

Below is a simple job design,

[image]

Since I do not have any database connection, I am using some static input from `tFixedFlowInput`. Below is the input data that I am using

[image]

- I am storing it in `tHashOutput_1` component.
- Then I am reading the same data available in `tHashOutput_1` using three `tHashInput` components.
- In `tMap` component, I am joining with different fields like below

[image]

Using this approach your problem would be solved.

**Note: If you could not able to find the `tHashOutput` and `tHashInput` component in your palette, then [you can follow this steps](http://garpitmzn.blogspot.in/2013/09/talend-enabling-unhiding-and-using.html)**

Comment: Hi. I tried your solution but it seems not to work. 
The lookup tables keep on loading separately one after each other.

![image](http://imgur.com/HDzTBqM)

Comment: Why does the row count varies between two `tHashInput` components?

Comment: The rows are different because it is still running, in fact the line is blue.

Comment: No. My question is, you have saved the data in `tHashOutput` component. Then if you read the same data in `tHashInput` components, then the number of rows need to be same. But in your case, `tHashInput_1` has same number of rows from `tHashOutput_1` component. And `tHashInput_2` is not having the same number of rows from `tHashOutput` component.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your point.

**tHashInput_1** completed the loading of all the rows, that are **20782613**, exactly the same as **tHashOutput**.

**tHashInput_2** was still loading at the time of the caption, and thus the number is different.

Comment: Oh ok Fine. I misunderstood. So what is the issue now?

Comment: It seems like the loockups are reloading, when I run the job. Hower in this way they are much more faster, so I used it.

Comment: If it solves your problem, kindly accept as correct answer, which may help others.

Comment: Done! Sorry I forgot it ;)